# Are custom adapters only used with ListView?

Tags: java, android, adapter, custom-adapter

I'm working on presentation about Custom Adapters in Android. So far from what I have seen is that Custom adapters are only used with ListView and nothing else. Is this a limitation or just a good approach ? Are there any other options from ViewGroup that can be used with Custom Adapters. If so can you share an example ?

Comment: Depends on your definition of custom. You can make your own adaptar to a recyclerview as well.

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84   Spinner with custom adapter, you can set custom adaper for many widgets  gridview, listview,recyclerview  etc

Answer (score 0):

There are many components that works with custom view here is some examples :

GridView

https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

RecycleView

[RecycleView Example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)

and ExpandableListView

[ExpandableListView Exaple](http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/07/android-simple-expandable-listview.html)

Answer (score 0):

> So far from what I have seen is that Custom adapters are only used with ListView and nothing else

No.

`ListView` inherits from a class named `AdapterView`. As the name suggests, `AdapterView` works with `Adapter` implementations. How "custom" those implementations are varies by developer. But, there are lots of subclasses of `AdapterView`, such as `GridView`, `Spinner`, `AutoCompleteTextView`, `ExpandableListView`, `StackView`, etc. All of them use `Adapter` implementations. [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection) contains many samples of `AdapterView` uses.

`RecyclerView` is an advanced replacement for some `AdapterView` scenarios, particularly lists and grids. `RecyclerView` has its own `RecyclerView.Adapter` that fills a similar role as does `Adapter`. [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView) contains many samples of using `RecyclerView`.

> Is this a limitation or just a good approach ?

Neither.

> Are there any other options from ViewGroup that can be used with Custom Adapters

There is nothing stopping you from creating your own subclass of `AdapterView`, though this gets rather complicated. You would be better served creating something based on `RecyclerView`, which is more flexible.

And, `RecyclerView` itself is "just" a `ViewGroup`, as is `AdapterView`. There is nothing stopping you from creating your own independent adapter-style set of classes, including some custom `ViewGroup`. This is *very* complicated.